# Filter in jquery for target matched LI

Tags: jquery

I want to pick matched Li html into div. I have made a function but it is updating div with li's test I want update li in html format like 'first' also it is removing li from ul, I dont want to remove li I just want to copy it pure html. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W5HZK/)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        var htm = '';
        var aa = [];
        if (txt.indexOf('first') > -1) {
            htm = $('ul').find('li').filter(function () {
                if ($(this).text().indexOf('first') > -1) {
                    return this;
                }
            })
            $('.first').html(htm)
        }
    })
})
</script>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
<li id="0">first</li>
<li id="1">first</li>
<li id="2">second</li>
<li id="3">first</li>
<li id="4">second</li>
<li id="5">second</li>
<li id="6">first</li>
</ul>
<a href="#">first html</a>
<a href="#">second html</a>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I want to display pure html like : '<li id='0'>first</li>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
// Filter the matched elements and clone them
htm = $('ul').find('li').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text().indexOf('first') > -1;
}).clone();

// Add the cloned elements to div
$('.first').html(htm);
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/W5HZK/3/)

Comment: I want to display pure html like : '<li id='0'>first</li>'